# Proxmox : Create VZ container from VM or container

Tags: proxmox

I'm running Proxmox v4.2-2. On it i've create some container based on Ubuntu 16.04 template.

Now, I need to customize the template. Add apt packages, customize some files, etc. How could I acheive this with ProxMox. There's some doc but always talking of using OpenVZ.

I've also create a Template from a VM, but also, it does not seemds to be a VZ template and I don't think I can export it.

Any idea how to acheive this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Full backup the VM and recorvey on all VM if you want.

Comment: I want to start from a VM and convert it to create a VZ template and start multiple VZ container. Not other VM.

Comment: Proxmox 4.x not supported OpenVZ. You must have LXC container. https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Convert_OpenVZ_to_LXC